# JBoss Error in ejb-jar.xml for Message Driven Bean TextMDB: expected one res-ref-name tag

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-mdb, ejb-2.x

I've copied and pasted the example ejb-jar.xml and jboss.xml file from http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch6.chapt.html#ch6.mdbejbjar.ex and I'm receiving the following error when JBoss attempts to deploy it:

```
ERROR [ScannerThread] deployment.MainDeployer (MainDeployer.java:943) - Could not create deployment: file:/...-ejb2.jar
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Error in ejb-jar.xml for Message Driven Bean TextMDB: expected one res-ref-name tag
    at org.jboss.metadata.ApplicationMetaData.importEjbJarXml(ApplicationMetaData.java:403)
    at org.jboss.metadata.XmlFileLoader.load(XmlFileLoader.java:151)
    at org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer.create(EJBDeployer.java:506)
```

Also, I've noticed in Eclipse that the sample ejb-jar.xml file I'm using doesn't conform to it's dtd.  Is there a better sample ejb2 mdb I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you fix the deployment descriptor? Try this `ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC 
          "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN"
          "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven>
            <ejb-name>TextMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>org.jboss.chap6.ex2.TextMDB</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
            <acknowledge-mode>AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</acknowledge-mode>
            <message-driven-destination>
                <destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</destination-type>
            </message-driven-destination>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>jms/QCF</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            </resource-ref>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another buggy example.  Changing it to conform to the dtd fixes the problem.

From:

```
        <res-ref-name>jms/QCF</res-ref-name>
        <resource-ref>
            <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
```

To:

```
        <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jms/QCF</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        </resource-ref>
```